# OSGI Disable org.apache.http.wire log

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-httpcomponents

I am using osgi httpcore;version=4.4.1 . I need to stop the debug logging of "org.apache.http.wire"

Is there any runtime config to disable this logging?

I have tried `log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=ERROR` in run time with no effect.

```
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                        <volumeSize>6</volumeSize>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                        <deleteOnTermination>true</deleteOnTermination>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                        <volumeType>standard</volumeType>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                        <encrypted>false</encrypted>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                    </ebs>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                </item>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            </blockDeviceMapping>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <virtualizationType>paravirtual</virtualizationType>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <hypervisor>xen</hypervisor>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "        </item>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "        <item>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <imageId>ami-30697651</imageId>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <imageLocation>057448758665/CentOS 7.2 x86_64 with cloud-init (PV)</imageLocation>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <imageState>available</imageState>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <imageOwnerId>057448758665</imageOwnerId>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <creationDate>2015-12-15T16:22:38.000Z</creationDate>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <isPublic>true</isPublic>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <architecture>x86_64</architecture>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <imageType>machine</imageType>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <kernelId>aki-fc8f11cc</kernelId>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <name>CentOS 7.2 x86_64 with cloud-init (PV)</name>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <description>Base CentOS 7.2.1511 with cloud-init ( use user ec2-user ), paravirtual and EBS backed. This image has been created with ComodIT. See how to build yours at http://www.comodit.com/2012/07/12/how-to-build-your-custom-centos-image-on-ec2</description>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <rootDeviceType>ebs</rootDeviceType>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <rootDeviceName>/dev/sda</rootDeviceName>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <blockDeviceMapping>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                <item>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                    <deviceName>/dev/sda</deviceName>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                    <ebs>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                        <snapshotId>snap-955a440c</snapshotId>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                        <volumeSize>6</volumeSize>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                        <deleteOnTermination>true</deleteOnTermination>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                        <volumeType>gp2</volumeType>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                        <encrypted>false</encrypted>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                    </ebs>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                </item>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            </blockDeviceMapping>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <virtualizationType>paravirtual</virtualizationType>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <hypervisor>xen</hypervisor>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "        </item>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "        <item>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <imageId>ami-3181cf01</imageId>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <imageLocation>057448758665/comodit-bootstrap-hvm</imageLocation>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <imageState>available</imageState>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <imageOwnerId>057448758665</imageOwnerId>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <creationDate>2014-10-24T11:01:30.000Z</creationDate>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <isPublic>true</isPublic>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <architecture>x86_64</architecture>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <imageType>machine</imageType>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <name>comodit-bootstrap-hvm</name>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <description>comodit-bootstrap-hvm</description>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <rootDeviceType>ebs</rootDeviceType>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <rootDeviceName>/dev/sda1</rootDeviceName>[\n]"
[Thread-522] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "            <blockDeviceMapping>[\n]"
```

Comment: What runtime do you use? Karaf, or plain framework? What logging system?

Comment: Hi, this log was printing when i use osgi aws sdk....i am using Amdatu

Comment: I am using org.apache.felix.framework.

Comment: The way to configure logging depends on the logging system you use. I am not familiar with the logging system in amdatu.